# How do I Change FXML Controller Variable Values in JavaFX before Showing Window?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I want to change the labels and text in a popup `FXML` window before it is shown. This is being done because all of the **Help** items will be very similar and I wanted to make a template `FXML` and then change the values of the labels and text area accordingly to reduce coding.

I'm surprised I haven't come across a template method in `JavaFX` though. If there's a better way to go about this, please do suggest it.

For the task at hand, I have the following:

```
@FXML
private void documentationAction(ActionEvent action) throws IOException {
    Stage dialogue = new Stage();
    Parent root = null;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("dialogues/dialogue.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    /*
     * change text values in title (Label) and text (TextArea)
     * and change the behavior of the findMore button
     */
    dialogue.setTitle("Documentation");
    dialogue.setScene(scene);
    dialogue.show();
}
```

I would like to be able to change variables inside the `FXM`L file, for which I've made `getters` and `setters` in the controller class, but I can't figure how to do this.

Is there a way?  It seems like it would be necessary for changing information between windows in multi-windowed applications, so I'm sure there's something simple that I'm missing.

UPDATE
Code for controller:

```
public class DialogueController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button more;
    @FXML
    private Button close;
    @FXML
    private TextArea text;
    @FXML
    private Label title;

    public TextArea getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text.setText(text);
    }

    public Label getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String text) {
        this.title.setText(text);
    }

    @FXML
    public void closeAction(ActionEvent action) {
        // get a handle to the stage
        Stage stage = (Stage) close.getScene().getWindow();
        // do what you have to do
        stage.close();
    }

    @FXML
    public void moreAction(ActionEvent action) {
    }

    @FXML
    public void makeDocumentation(ActionEvent action) {
        this.title.setText("Documentation");
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }
}
```

Full Dialogue FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" padding="$x1" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="400.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="pdbpro.dialogues.DialogueController">
  <children>
    <GridPane alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <children>
        <Label fx:id="title" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefWidth="-1.0" styleClass="title" text="Title" underline="false" visible="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
          <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets fx:id="x1" />
          </GridPane.margin>
        </Label>
        <TextArea fx:id="text" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" prefWidth="200.0" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
          <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="24.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" />
          </GridPane.margin>
        </TextArea>
        <ToolBar GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
          <items>
            <Button fx:id="more" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Find more" />
            <Button fx:id="close" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeAction" text="Close" />
          </items>
          <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="14.0" />
          </GridPane.margin>
        </ToolBar>
      </children>
      <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      </columnConstraints>
      <padding>
        <Insets fx:id="x1" />
      </padding>
      <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="60.0" minHeight="60.0" prefHeight="60.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="0.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      </rowConstraints>
    </GridPane>
  </children>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@dialogue.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

Full stack trace of error at these lines

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("dialogues/dialogue.fxml"));
DialogueController dc = loader.getController();
dc.makeDocumentation(); //ERROR
Scene scene = new Scene(root);


java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1440)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:456)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1188)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$6.handle(ContextMenuContent.java:1139)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$6.handle(ContextMenuContent.java:1137)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3324)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1435)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pdbpro.MainController.documentationAction(MainController.java:82)
    ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 5):

One way I can see is to make your controller implement initializable and implement the initialize method. The initialize method will be called automatically when the controller is created by the fxml loader. When the inititialize method is called all the fxml object declared should be initialized and ready to be customized.

[edit] 
After reading the [docs for initializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html),
it says that if a method called initialize with no args is created that it will be called automatically with the fxml loader. So from what I understand, you don't need to implement initializable. Just create an initialize method with no args.

If needed, further info may be found in [an introduction to fxml](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers).

Comment: The controller is already initialized, but the initialize method was, in this case, blank:     
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }

If I wanted to then edit the fields of the class, I tried Uluk's suggestion, but I got a null pointer.  Could you expand on what you meant?
Thanks!

Comment: In that method you'd do your customization that you want. You can call your getters and setters and do everything to change the labels and anything you need to from within the controller since the initialize method is already inside it

Comment: What would I pass to the initializer to indicate what values I want set during the initialization?  Or how would I add another parameter to the method, say a string, to indicate to what I want the values initialized?

Comment: You can't pass it another parameter. What I would do is create a model for the controller and pass that the parameters you want and then in the inititialize method in the controller, it would talk to the model to get the values it needs

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("dialogues/dialogue.fxml").openStream());
DialogueController dc = loader.getController();
dc.setTitle("title");
dc.setTextArea("text");
// and so on..
...
dialogue.show();
```

Assert that the DialogueController dc is not null. And assuming the "title" is a Label in fxml file with `fx:id=titleLabel`, it should be backed in your controller class like follows:

```
...
@FXML private Label titleLabel;
...
public void setTitle(String txt) {
    titleLabel.setText(txt);
}
...
```

Comment: I got a null pointer exception with this on the setTitle line.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at pdbpro.MainController.documentationAction(MainController.java:84)

Comment: @Kylamus. Have you defined fx:controller attribute in your dialogue.fxml? And did that controller's initialize method run while loading dialogue.fxml?

Comment: It appears to all be initialized properly and the controller has been fully defined.

Comment: @Kylamus. Then your DialogueController should not be null at line dc.setTitle("title");. The NPE comes from setTitle() I guess. Can I see the code of controller class at least getters/setters? See update.

Comment: reduced code::

`public class DialogueController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private Button more;
    @FXML
    private Button close;
    @FXML
    private TextArea text;
    @FXML
    private Label title;

    public TextArea getText() {
        return text;
    }
    
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text.setText(text);
    }
    
    public void setTitle(String text) {
        this.title.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }
}`

Comment: @Kylamus. It seems ok. Can you verify the label title is not null at this.title.setText(text) when dc.setTitle() is called.

Comment: This still seems to give a null pointer, but not because the title restaurant is null, because of a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
`        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("dialogues/dialogue.fxml"));
        DialogueController dc = loader.getController();
        dc.setText("blah blah");
        dc.setTitle("Documentation");`

Comment: @Kylamus. Post the dialogue.fxml file and the full stacktrace of an exception.

Comment: Everything has been posted.

Comment: @Kylamus. My bad, the answer was incomplete. See update diff (note openStream). HTH.

Comment: Upon further inspection, the exceptions are now being thrown at the line: `        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("dialogues/dialogue.fxml").openStream());`  This error is, however, not thrown without the .openStream().  Without the openStream, no error is reached with `DialogueController dc = loader.getController();`. However, when I try dc.getTitle(), a null pointer results in an invocation exception again, suggesting that you are correct that the initialize method is not run properly when loading. How do I look deeper into that?  
Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: @Uluk : This helped. If you happen to read this comment... any idea why it works when loading using an input stream (.openStream()) and not when passing a URL ? The API doc for both methods is the same...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to hide all FXML loading code to controller. For that it is possible to extend a Stage class:

Controller:

```
public class DialogueController extends Stage implements Initializable{
    @FXML private Button more;
    @FXML private Button close;
    @FXML private TextArea text;
    @FXML private Label title;

    public DialogueController(Parent parent){
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("dialogues/dialogue.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        super.setTitle("Documentation");
        try{
            setScene(new Scene((Parent) loader.load()));
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
        /*
         * Change values here
         */     
    }   
}
```

Call your controller:

```
@FXML
private void documantationAction(ActionEvent action) throws IOException{
    DialogueController controller = new DialogueController(null);
    controller.show();
}
```